# How do I validate all form fields in a div using parsley.js?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, parsley.js

I have a div with a form field and a button that I would like to have parsley validate all the form fields in that div that have the proper `data-validate` attribute. I need it to work no matter how many form fields are in the div. So it needs to work on inputs, textareas, and select fields.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parsley-div">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="city">City</label>
    <input id="city-test" type="text" class="form-control" data-parsley-required data-parsley-required-message="Please enter a city name.">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#parsley-div').find('button').click(function(){
  $('#parsley-div').parsley().validate();
});
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working. I noticed it works if there is a form tag around the form fields, but I need it to be a div. I have created a JSFiddle that shows both cases: https://jsfiddle.net/8rkxzjx1/2/

How can I have parsley validate all form fields with `data-parsley` attributes within a specified div? If possible, please edit the JSFiddle to show the correct implementation. Thank you.

**Edit:**

I figured out this works, but it doesn't feel very efficient:

```
$('#parsley-div').find( "input, textarea, select" ).each(function (index, value) {   
  $(this).parsley().validate();
});
```

Comment: zeck, I have updated the answer. these are what I've came up with. I'm not sure if there'a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use

```
$('#parsley-div :input:not(:button)').parsley().validate();
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8rkxzjx1/3/).

**Edit**

Looks like the above code won't work. The following can be used as the OP suggested.

```
$('#parsley-div :input:not(:button)').each(function (index, value) { 
  $(this).parsley().validate();
});
```

Here is the new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HLUkq/55/).

Or the content can be wrapped in a form element and then be validated as follows:

```
$("#parsley-div").wrap("<form id='parsley-form'></form>");
$('#parsley-div').find('button').click(function() {
    $('#parsley-form').parsley().validate();
});
```

Or since the OP does not want to have a form element in Dom, content can be wrapped in a form element and then the form can be removed after validation.

```
$('#parsley-div').find('button').click(function() {
    $("#parsley-div").wrap("<form id='parsley-form'></form>");
    $('#parsley-form').parsley().validate();
    $("#parsley-div").unwrap();
});
```

Links to [fiddle-wrap](http://jsfiddle.net/HLUkq/59/) and [fiddle-wrap-unwrap](http://jsfiddle.net/HLUkq/60/).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I need it to work for textareas and selects too.

Comment: I sort of figured out a solution that works for all those cases (See edit area in description), but it doesn't feel very efficient and I feel there should be a cleaner solution.

Comment: @zeckdude `$('#parsley-form').parsley().validate();` looks like it's doing the exact thing as `.each(function ())`. so your solution seems to be the most appropriate one.